# Regular expression for port number in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a scenario that, a string should accept only numbers and comma, In between comma the number should be in range of 0 to 999.

**Valid case:**

```
322,333,459,999,000,001
```

**Invalid case:**

```
32222,44444444444,666666,
```

I tried with this regular expression `[0-9{3},/,]+`. It only allows comma and numbers.

But how can we restrict to 3 digits in between the comma.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `[\d{3},]+` enough ? I don't know why you've put `/` in your regex.

Comment: @naurel not really, unless you want to allow the following characters: digits, `{`, `3`, `}`, `,`. The square brackets denote a character class, so only the *characters* within are allowed. Most of the symbols that have special meaning in regex loose it in there.

Comment: `(?:\d{3}|,)+` might be better.

Comment: @naurel `"100,200,300,"` passes now. Also `","` or `",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"` and `"100200300"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`^\d{3}(,\d{3})*$`

---

`^`  : beginning of line

`\d` : digit

`{3}`: 3 times

`*`  : 0 or more times

`$`  : end of line

---

**EDIT:**

In case you do not plan to reuse the group (expression between parantheses) you can make it non-capturing with `?:`. It will look like that:

`^\d{3}(?:,\d{3})*$`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for :

```
^(?:\d{1,3},)*\d{1,3}$
```

To awnser your exact question `.{1,3}` means that you want any character to be present between 1 and 3 times. This way you limit occurrences.